# In Xaml, how do you change the value of the SolidColorBrush programmatically?

Tags: xaml, binding, solidcolorbrush

Hi I have a xaml app that has one particular color used in many places on a page.  I want to programmatically change the value of this color.  I don't want to have to update every object's color individually.  I have tried this:

```
<Grid
   Background="{Binding GalleryViewBrush, Mode=TwoWay}"
   Grid.Row="0"
   Grid.Column="0">
```

Then in codebehind:

public Brush GalleryViewBrush { get; set; }

GalleryViewBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

But the color never works.  I have tried xbind too but no luck

thanks

Comment: And remove `Mode=TwoWay` from the Binding. It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your view model needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and then fire the `PropertyChanged` event when your brush property changes. Conventionally that's done in the setter for the property.

```
private Brush _myBrush;
public MyBrush {
    get { return _myBrush; }
    set {
        _myBrush = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MyBrush));
    }
}
```

If your get/set for `GalleryViewBrush` in your question is what's actually in the code sample in your question, that's likely to be the issue.

Mind typos in my code sample above, I'm hammered ATM.